# jquery. Get base64 dynamic div background image and get width / height of the base64 dynamic background image

Tags: jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/qkzmegkb/5/

Have div

```
<div id="large_photo" style="width:20px; height:20px; 
background-image: url( data:image/JPG;base64,R0lGODlh... );" >
</div>
```

`background-image` changes depending on circumstances (`background-image` is dynamic; is not static).

With jquery want to get width and height of `background-image`

Did:

```
var image = document.createElement('img');//as understand i create some image (img)

//creating value for var image
var val = $('#large_photo').css('background-image'), image;
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("data:image/") + 0);//get part of string starting with `data:image/`
image.src = myString;
```

With `alert(image.width + ' × ' + image.height);` see `0 x 0`

For comparison this works:

```
var myString = 'data:image/JPG;base64,R0lGODlhCgAKAJEAAJmZmf////4BAgAAACH5BAQUAP8ALAAAAAAKAAoAAAIIhI+py+0PYysAOw==';
image.src = myString;
alert(image.width + ' × ' + image.height);
```

How to get to work the first variant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**`substring()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) function to get **`base64 image source`**,

Once you get image source you can assign to new created **`image`** element. **`image`** element **`property (width and height)`** to get image **`width/height`**.

**View this** <kbd>[Live](http://jsfiddle.net/qkzmegkb/11/)</kbd>

#### JQuery

```
var image = document.createElement('img');
var val = $('#large_photo').css('background-image');
var myString = val.substring(4, val.length-1);

image.src = myString;

alert( image.src );
alert(image.width + ' × ' + image.height);
```

#### Result

```
10 x 10
```

---

Easiest way to learn code,

**View this** <kbd>[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qkzmegkb/12/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution
http://jsfiddle.net/qkzmegkb/10/

Problem was because `var val = $('#large_photo').css('background-image'), image;` ends with `")`. So simply need to remove `")`. I did it with `myString = myString.replace('")', '');`

So here is code

```
var image = document.createElement('img');//create element image
var val = $('#large_photo').css('background-image'), image;//get image from div
var myString = val.substr(val.indexOf("data:image") + 0);//remove all before `data:image`
myString = myString.replace('")', ''); // remove `")`
image.src = myString;//pass content to `image`

alert( image.src );
alert(image.width + ' × ' + image.height);
```